# Seleciona post ordenado por id

Tags: php, html5, mysqli

opa, eai amigos... bom, o problema que estou tendo, fiz uma consulta ao banco de dados onde pego todos os posts ordenado por id decrescente, e simplesmente nao funciona... ele seleciona apenas o primeiro.

segue o codigo

```
<?php
    include 'connect.php';
$title = null;
$text = null;
    $select = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY idp DESC");
    // $conta = mysqli_num_rows($select);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($select) <= 0) {
            echo "<script>alert('Nao ha posts')</script>";
        }else{
            while ($in = mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {
                $title = $in['titulo'];
                $text = $in['texto'];
                $id = $in['idp'];
            }
        }
?>
<div class="wrap-p">
    <div id="title"><?php echo $title;?></div>
    <div id="texto"><?php echo $text;?></div>
    <div id="texto"><?php echo "$id";?></div>
</div>
</div><br><br>

<div class="wrap-p">
    <div id="title"><?php echo $title;?></div>
    <div id="texto"><?php echo $text;?></div>
    <div id="texto"><?php echo "$id";?></div>
</div>
</div><br><br>
```

Comment: Parece que suas variáveis não listas. Transforma elas em array e vai adicionando conforme a consulta trouxer resultado, aí faz um for pra renderizar isso em HTML.

Comment: Ola @leandro, Bem vindo ao SOpt, antes de começar faça uma visita ao nosso [Tour].

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que seu problema é que seu HTML esta fora do `while`, por isso ele só esta mostrando o ultimo item da sua interação.

```
<?php
    include 'connect.php';
    $title = null;
    $text = null;
    $select = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY idp DESC");
    // $conta = mysqli_num_rows($select);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($select) <= 0) {
            echo "<script>alert('Nao ha posts')</script>";
        }else{
            while ($in = mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {
                $title = $in['titulo'];
                $text = $in['texto'];
                $id = $in['idp'];

         # ; toda vez que o while passar aki ele vai adicionar esse trecho
         # ; de codigo HTML na pagina, ou seja, para cada registro retornado
         # ; ele vai adicionar o $title, $text, e $id
?>

<div class="wrap-p">
    <div id="title"><?php echo $title;?></div>
    <div id="texto"><?php echo $text;?></div>
    <div id="texto"><?php echo "$id";?></div>
</div>
<br><br>

<?php

            } # ; <- fim do while
        }     # ; <- fim do else
?>
```

No código acima eu estou abrindo e fechando a tag php varias vezes, nesse caso você também pode fazer uso do formato [**heredoc** `<<<`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) pode criar um string de saída, veja o exemplo:

```
<?php
    include 'connect.php';

    $select = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY idp DESC");
    // $conta = mysqli_num_rows($select);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($select) <= 0) {
            echo "<script>alert('Nao ha posts')</script>";
        }else{
            while ($in = mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {

                # ; inicio da string, abri ela com o texto HTML
                echo <<<HTML

<div class="wrap-p">
    <div id="title">{$in['titulo']}</div>
    <div id="texto">{$in['texto']}</div>
    <div id="texto">{$in['idp']}</div>
</div>
<br><br>

HTML;
# ; ^ fim da string fechar ela com o 
# ; mesmo texto da abertura no caso HTML
# ; [NOTA] não pode haver nada alem do `HTML;` nesta
# ; linha, no teste no ideone até um ` ` (espaço) 
# ; apos o `;` gerou erro

            } # ; <- fim do while
        }     # ; <- fim do else

?>
```

[Exemplo online](https://ideone.com/hYksUf)

Comment: Tentei colocar isso... nada aparece na tela

Comment: Atualizei o primeiro código colocando a `<?php` ao inves da *short tag* `<?`, e no segundo código tirei o comentário na linha em que esta o fim do **heredoc**, adicionei um exemplo online.